# Fast way to initialize class variables in Python

Tags: python, class-method

I would like to initialize an instance and let both args and kwargs become class variables.

```py
class Example():
    def __init__(
        self,
        a: str,
        b: bool,
        c: int,
        d="str",
        e=True,
        f=123,
    ):
        class_member = dict(locals())
        del class_member["self"]
        self.set_property(class_member)

    @classmethod
    def set_property(cls, kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(cls, key, value)

a = Example("test", True, 1, d="test", e=False, f=456)
print(Example.d)  # test
```

I have searched a lot and get the above result.

Is there any other cleaner way to deal with that? Thanks!

--Edit--

Thanks for all answers.
My simplified version:

```py
class Example():
    def __init__(
        self,
        a: str,
        b: bool,
        c: int,
        d="str",
        e=True,
        f=123,
    ):
        class_member = dict(locals())
        del class_member["self"]
        for key, value in class_member.items():
            setattr(Example, key, value)

a = Example("test", True, 1, d="test", e=False, f=456)
print(Example.d)  # test
```

I had thought about using `**kwarg` previously, but I still need to assign default value for kwargs. So this is my final solution.

Comment: It looks as good as it'll get, really. It's just that this is inherently messy; classes are intended to hold stuff common to all instances, not depend on the latest one.

Comment: what's the use-case for this?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko
I need to import `Example` class in other file (module) to access the class variable of `Example` after `a` is instanced.

Comment: That's… still not very clear, and sounds potentially extremely yucky as far as OOP and sane program structure is concerned.

Comment: I have tried my best to make it OOP. The other classes need Example.d, Example.e and Example.f. Maybe there is other method to pass these variables.

Comment: Maybe what are you looking for is a design pattern called "singleton". But the thing you are doing looks like some object keeping configuration? In such case I'd recommend [Pydantic Settings class](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/)

Comment: My use-case is here if you not mind to see my messy codes. :(

My intention is to take `impute_method` from [dataset](https://github.com/deeperlearner/pytorch-template/blob/master/data_loaders/examples/Adult_dataset.py) and use it in [model](https://github.com/deeperlearner/pytorch-template/blob/master/models/model.py).
The class indeed creates once but it is a little different from singleton. Pydantic not sure :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `setattr` and `kwargs` only:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(Example, k, v)


a = Example(a="test", b=True, c=1, d="test", e=False, f=456)
print(Example.d)  # test
```